# Float multiplication

Tags: python, python-2.7, precision

In python does anybody know how to save insignificant `0`, i.e

```
x=9999.0
y=.01
print x*y
```

The output is `99.99` but i want `99.990`.Can this happen?

I am not sure if formatting can achieve this.In nutshell i need to save `0`'s.

So it has to be generic.It can also be

```
x=9999.5
y=.01
```

Then we dont need formatting there.Only as places we lose `0`.Also it need to not `5` digits always.It can be less or more.So somehow we need to detect the `0` we are losing and then append it

Comment: `99.99` is the same as `99.990`. What you are looking for is string formatting. Read https://pyformat.info/ for an intro.

Comment: @KlausD. i cant use string-formatting as it can be `9998.5` * `.01`....then it wont work in that case...how i can make it generic to save `0`'s

Comment: Then give a list of floats (the results for your computation and the desired output of the print!

Comment: I'm still wondering what you are actually asking. `print "%.03f" % your_float` should do the job.

Comment: @KlausD. no it wont .... zerek's answer would work if i some how can set `getcontext().prec` programmatically

Comment: So, what should `9998.5 * .01` print, if not `99.985`? *"make it generic to save 0's"* makes no sense.

Comment: @SiHa  it can be `101.1` * `.01` or `101.01`*`.001`

Comment: If it is about precision: `99.99` as a float is not more precise than `99.99000000`. It is the same float. You can only represent it differently, with or without trailing zeros. But still it is the same number: `99.99 == 99.9900000000000` → `True`.

Comment: @KlausD. i know but i want it that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the decimal module:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 5
>>> Decimal(9999.0) * Decimal(0.01)
Decimal('99.990')
```

Comment: Can we get this `getcontext().prec` from a number?like if i say `9999.5` then can we get that programmatically as `5`?

Comment: Maybe you can convert your number to a string and count the characters, after removing . and -

Comment: @navit yes i can do that but just wanted to know `decimal` module provides something

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of numbers after the decimal point with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). Try this in the console:

```
>>> print '%.3f' % (9999.0*.01)
99.990
```

Comment: Anyhow you must define your precision when working with floats. I don't understand what you mean by saving 0's.

Comment: I think he means [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in version 2.7

```
x=9999.0
y=.01
print '%.3f' % (x*y)
```

Read about python formatting [here](https://pyformat.info/)